# ubuntu 12.04 autoclick

Tags: 12.04, tabs

I dont know how to search for this problem.. more and more frequently when I start and login my machine, it opens the desktop, and as I open a folder, or if I go on the internet, it will just start opening tabs after tabs after tabs.. I only know how to shut of the machine to fix this, and hope next time it will have gone away. sometimes I have to restart two times for it to begone. What is this? How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it might sound obvious, but it might be good to first check the simple solutions. have you tried to disconnect your keyboard or to plug in an other keyboard (if you have one laying around). If it for some reason sends a alt-t signal it could explain the problem.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that is probably it. It seems like it is a keyboard, or mouse signal gone awry. No havent tried the obvious :P Gonna check it out next time it happens :)